# How to extract Requests/Seconds (Throughput) of a performance test using Locust?

Tags: python-3.x, throughput, locust

I am running Locust performance Test against an API and I need to plot a Requests/Second vs Response time plot. I can see the req/s as a parameter in the results of the tests. Is there a Library/Class from where I can directly access this parameter ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at using the master report / slave report event hook (depending on where you want to log it from?

https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#locust.events.EventHook

You havent said how you want to plot it, but we use something similar to shunt the metrics into a database to report on.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the `_requests.csv` and `_distribution.csv` files that get generated if you pass in the `--csv` flag. These contain the requests/s column as well as the response times for different percentiles and also min, max, medain and avg.
https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/retrieving-stats.html